# XML5632: Only one root element is allowed - Microsoft Add-In

Tags: reactjs, xml, outlook, windows-10, outlook-addin

I'm currently working on an issue with a Microsoft Edge Add-In written in React in which state changes aren't working, and I can't see any of my console logs.

**Some context:** 
I have a web Add-In for Microsoft Outlook desktop that I am trying to run on Windows 10 version 1903. I've added console logs to the event handlers of a few button clicks and several other events throughout the app, but none of these console logs actually show up in the Microsoft Edge DevTools console. I can see calls to `console.log('We just clicked a button')` in the compiled JavaScript file in the Debugger, so my changes are being picked up and are in fact there, but no actual console logs show up inside of the DevTools console. The only error I see in DevTools is `XML5632: Only one root element is allowed` on `index.html (1, 1)`.

I should note that the web Add-In works in Microsoft Outlook desktop on later versions of Windows 10, but running it on version 1903 is the only time that it's problematic.

An answer on this forum: https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/20753/xml5632-only-one-root-element-is-allowed-error-on-windows-edge/#Post88600 suggests it's a problem with Edge interpreting an Ajax call as XML, but doesn't elaborate much more beyond that.

My guess is that this a JavaScript issue with pre-Chromium Edge, but I'd like to know if anyone has any suggestions on a workaround or fix so that I can 1.) Resolve the issue with the state change in my React app and 2.) See my console logs.

Comment: Read [ask].  Then [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.  In the meantime, it may help to know that XML documents are only allowed to have a single root element.  All XML parsers and tools expect a single root element, and if they find multiple, they will issue such an error message and terminate.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? I'm facing a similar problem with the OfficeJS libary.

Comment: Solution for this?